# Change the axis type of an Excel chart using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

How do I change the axis type of an Excel chart's X axis using PowerShell?

To do this manually using Excel:

- open workbook in Excel
- select X axis chart
- select "Axis options"
- configure "Text axis" under the "Axis Type" option

Update: it's XLSX format. I should clarify: the issue is that the data set I'm plotting uses dates on the x axis and Excel is intelligently filling in the gaps (so if I have May 5 and May 7 in the data set, Excel plots May 6 too). Swapping to Text appears to fix this issue in the Excel app. I wish to automate this like the rest of my data analysis and charting.

Comment: What format, XLS or XLSX?

Comment: @Taosique please see the question update. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There you are:

```
# Launch Excel:
$app = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application

# Open a Workbook:
$app.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Workbook.xlsx")

# Activate the chart you need (note: you don't need full path with filename now):
$app.Workbooks("Workbook.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate()

# Change the category type of axis. Axes(1) means category axis. Possible values:
# xlCategoryScale = 2
# xlTimeScale = 3
# xlAutomaticScale = -4105
$app.ActiveChart.Axes(1).CategoryType = 2

# Save & close the workbook
$app.Workbooks("Workbook.xlsx").Close($True)
```

You can now return to step 2, open another workbook and repeat these actions.
After you're done, close the Excel application and clean up:

```
$app.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($app)
Remove-Variable app
```

Comment: Thank you for both the answer and the last bit that releases the ComObject. I suspect you'll say experience but may I ask what documentation you used, e.g. to find out the TimeScale value or the Axes(1) meaning?

Comment: I used these references: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlcategorytype.aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlaxistype.aspx .To find values, I used Excel VBA editor: stepped on breakpoint and added watch for `xlCategory` to see it equals `1`. Also its a good way to find what VBA code you need by recording a macro, doing things manually in Excel and then looking at the code it generates.